# XML Parsing in liquid

Tags: xml, shopify, liquid

My XML looks like:

```
<examplexml>
    <nest1>
        <nest2>
             <nest3>
                <mean>5</mean>
                <stdeviation>0.1</stdeviation>
             </nest3>
        </nest2>
     </nest1>
    <nest1>
        <nest2>
             <nest3>
                <mean>7</mean>
                <stdeviation>0.2</stdeviation>
             </nest3>
        </nest2>
     </nest1>
</examplexml>
```

I'm stuck using Liquid on this project and I want to parse this xml.  I can get the mean once by doing

```
{{ file.parse.examplexml.nest1.nest2.nest3.mean }}
```

but I want to get all the means, so I thought I could do

```
{% for nest1 in file.parse.examplexml.nest1 %}
  {{ nest1.nest2.nest3.mean }}
{% endfor %}
```

But this prints out nothing.  However if I do

```
{% for nest1 in file.parse.examplexml.nest1 %}
  {{ nest1 }}
{% endfor %}
```

I get nest2.  So I'd think I can access the mean through the nest2 and nest3 properties, but it doesn't seem to work that way as far as I know.  Is there a way to do this in Liquid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You cannot parse XML with Liquid. Doing so is like trying to run your car on dishwashing soap. You may get a sputter at first that makes you think it'll go, but in the end, your car will sit in the parking lot till you clean out the gasline and add gas.

Parsing XML is for something like Nokogiri. Whoever stuck you with Liquid, should stick you with Nokogiri, the right tool for the job.